# Type error in pandas and excel read in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I have a for loop to create a Pandas data-frame from an excel workbook with multiple sheets. Effectively, I want a create a data-frame by selecting the data in a particular column from all the sheets in an excel workbook. My code is the following.

```
  for sheet in sheetnames:
    df1[sheet]=pd.read_excel('P:/ITM/egi_esa/1.Users_Personal_Folders/Vignesh/JRC/Wind_TEMBA.xlsx',sheet_name=sheet,usecols='J')
```

where sheetnames is a list with the names (4 character strings) of the different sheets in the excel workbook. When I run the code for the first time, there is no error. But , when I run it for the second time, I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e1db6061ba75> in <module>
      1 for sheet in sheetnames:
----> 2     df1[sheet]=pd.read_excel('P:/ITM/egi_esa/1.Users_Personal_Folders/Vignesh/JRC/Wind_TEMBA.xlsx',sheet_name=sheet,usecols='J')

TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

Can someone help me with understanding why it works for the first time and not from the second instance.

Best
v

Comment: What is df1.? is it a dict.?

Comment: df1 is an empty dataframe.

Comment: @Sreeram TP: thanks for your suggestion. taking the sheets into a dictionary was easier. I am not sure why the reply is not visible anymore. Thanks

Comment: Check the answer now. If it helped do accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read all the sheets in the `excel` file into a `dict` with `key` is the sheet name and `value` is the data frame for the sheet you can see this code,

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('excel_file_path.xls')

# Now you can list all sheets in the file
xls.sheet_names
# ['sheet1', 'sheet2', ...]

sheet_to_df_map = {}
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
    sheet_to_df_map[sheet_name] = xls.parse(sheet_name)
```

This can be done with a single line code like this

```
sheet_to_df_map = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)
```

You will get an `OrderedDict`

After that, you can loop through the dictionary values and take the column you need and make the final dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()


for key, data in sheet_to_df_map.items():

    if 'J' in data.columns:
        df1[key] = data['J']
    else:
        df1[key] = [np.nan] * len(data)

print(df1)
```

This will only work if the length of all the sheets is the same, ie every sheet has the same number of rows.